# How to solve illegal start of expression in line number 27, 43?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

```
package ramo.klevis.ui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by klevis.ramo on 11/29/2017.
 */
public class ProgressBar {

    private final JFrame mainFrame;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private boolean unDecoreate = false;

    public ProgressBar(JFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        progressBar = createProgressBar(mainFrame);
    }

    public ProgressBar(JFrame mainFrame, boolean unDecoreate) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        progressBar = createProgressBar(mainFrame);
        this.unDecoreate = unDecoreate;
    }

    public void showProgressBar(String msg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            if (unDecoreate) {
                mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
            }
            progressBar = createProgressBar(mainFrame);
            progressBar.setString(msg);
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            mainFrame.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            if (unDecoreate) {
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
            mainFrame.repaint();
        });
    }


    private JProgressBar createProgressBar(JFrame mainFrame) {
        JProgressBar jProgressBar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
        jProgressBar.setVisible(false);
        mainFrame.add(jProgressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return jProgressBar;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        progressBar.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Line numbers 23, 47 error occurred 'illegal start of expression'.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues when I try to compile it - might be an old/cached error or an encoding issue (like a invisible character)

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { //error occured

Comment: Please copy the error message verbatim into your question, adding the version of the Java environment.

Comment: D:\>javac ProgressBar.java
ProgressBar.java:27: illegal start of expression
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->
                                    ^
ProgressBar.java:27: illegal start of expression
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->
                                      ^
ProgressBar.java:28: illegal start of expression
                {
                ^
ProgressBar.java:44: illegal start of expression
        });
         ^
4 errors    jdk1.6 version use

Comment: (There are reasons why I explicitly suggested to copy the message to the question: a) it belongs there to make the question answerable b) it is not really intelligible in a comment.) English wikipedia on Java version history: [Lambda \[was\] dropped from Java 7](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7).

Comment: i installed jdk1.8 the coding run..